# How to run a action after another in RecursiveASTVisitor?

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, clang++

I write a clang plugin, now there are three class TestConsumer, TestAction, TestVisitor.
In TestVisitor, I have do action in VisitObjCPropertyDecl and VisitCallExpr.

I want the Visitor first visit all ObjCPropertyDecl, and store name of Decl in a vector, then, visit all CallExpr, and if a name exist in vector but not exist in all call expr, raise a Diag error.

So how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find one way by myself.

In TestAction, there is `virtual bool EndSourceFileAction() {}` method, override this. Or just do final action in `~TestVisitor() {}`.